# passing genric class as fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am creating utility class that pass class name that extends fragment. but fragment method are not available in method declaration.
code snippet to return fragment tag.

```
private String createFragmentTag(Class<? extends  Fragment> aClass, boolean addArgs) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(aClass.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if(addArgs) {
            stringBuilder.append("-");
            **//here get argument is not calling**
            if (aClass.getArguments() != null)
                stringBuilder.append(aClass.getArguments().toString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Of course you cannot call `getArguments()` on a `Class` object. The `Class` class has no such method. You need to pass an actual instance of a `Fragment` to your method to call `getArguments()`.

Comment: thanks. i got it. i will do it in other way

Comment: So? How does that make it impossible? What you are trying is not possible, what I am suggesting is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String createFragmentTag(Fragment fragment, boolean addArgs) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if(addArgs) {
        stringBuilder.append("-");
        **//here get argument is not calling**
        if (fragment.getArguments() != null)
            stringBuilder.append(fragment.getArguments().toString());
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Would work. Like was mentioned in the comments, `aClass` doesn't have a `getArguments()` method because you haven't instantiated the class it represents yet. If instead you pass the actual instantiated `Fragment` class as a parameter, then you can accomplish your actual goal of generating a unique string tag for that fragment.